# How to populate a Word doc from a new SP List Item- but using Flow instead of SPD?

Tags: workflow

I'd like to be able to generate a Word doc from a template that is populated with data from whenever a new SP List item is created.

I've been reading through this walk-though and it describes the process.

https://sharepointprojectbrad.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/create-word-2013-documents-from-sharepoint-2013-list-items/

However, I hit a problem when it comes to setting up the workflow to take the List Item data and make the Word doc. This guide describes how to create the workflow in SPD- but I don;t have access to SPD. I can set up workflows in Microsoft Flows, but I don't have the knowledge or familiarity with that product to replicate the required steps.

Would anyone happen to have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Plumsail Documents](https://plumsail.com/documents/) to generate PDF documents from templates with the help of Microsoft Flow. You can get SharePoint list item and then apply it to HTML or DOCX template. Once applied you can convert result document to PDF.

Two articles describing how to do this:

- [Create PDF from DOCX template](https://plumsail.com/docs/documents/v1.x/flow/how-tos/documents/create-pdf-from-docx-template.html)
- [Create PDF from HTML template](https://plumsail.com/docs/documents/v1.x/flow/how-tos/documents/create-pdf-from-html-template.html)

Note: This is a paid solution and I'm a member of dev team.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the document library with the custom content type containing the Word template and metadata fields (same as in list). Then in Word you can use Smart Field feature to get the data from document list and populate in the document. One thing whenever metadata will change that will affect the document as well.